# mentionedUser.joinedAt returns `undefined`

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Here's my code:

```js
const userEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

            .setAuthor(mentionedUser.username, mentionedUser.displayAvatarURL())
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Created', value: mentionedUser.createdAt.toUTCString(), inline: true },
                { name: 'Joined', value: mentionedUser.joinedAt, inline: true }, << This line >>
            )
            .setColor('#05e6ff')
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(`ID: ${mentionedUser.id}`)
```

The mentionedUser var is just the user you mentioned (if none the mentionedUser is the author of the message/command)

Comment: `joinedAt` only exists on `GuildMember`s and not on `User`s. 

`mentionedUser` is a `User`, and does not have the `joinedAt` property.

Comment: So what do i do now?

Comment: You can find the corresponding `GuildMember` for the `mentionedUser` and get the `joinedAt` property from the `GuildMember` instead.

Comment: Can you teach/help me with finding that? I don't think I can do this myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [user15517071](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15517071/user15517071) stated, `.joinedAt` is a GuildMember property and not a User property. To get the GuildMember property you can either

**A: Grab the mentioned member object**

```
// Instead of
const mentionedUser = message.mentions.users.first();

// Do
const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();
```

**B: Given the User Object, Fetch Using The ID**

```
let memberObj;
message.guild.members.fetch(mentionedUser.id).then(res => memberObj = res);
// You can also use async/await, or work inside the scope of .then(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the GuildMember for the mentionedUser like so:

```js
const member = await message.guild.members.fetch(mentionedUser);
```

You can then get their joinedAt Date with `member.joinedAt`.

---

Understanding the difference between a user and a member is helpful in this situation. A GuildMember is a User that is in a Guild (server). You can get the user of a GuildMember trivially, but you need both the User and a Guild to get the required GuildMember.

Comment: This still returns undefined, did i miss something?
i have `const member = message.guild.members.fetch(mentionedUser);` and then in my embed
`{ name: 'Joined', value: member.joinedAt, inline: true },`

Comment: I answered that with the assumption that `message` is, well, the message that initiated all of this. Is the assumption true?

Comment: Hm? i don't understand that really much sorry, do you  mean I may have to do `message.member.joinedAt`? Or am I just really "blind"

Comment: Oops, missed await. My fault.

Comment: i couldn't save both answers as right, but they defiantly are!

Comment: That's fine. Glad to have helped!